# Am I eligible to use content of questions in my educational materials?

Tags: discussion, support

I would like to create a tutorial/book/materials on a using a Virtual Layer in QGIS. My aim is to expand the [QGIS's documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) with practical examples, demonstrating the usage of the VL in solving real problems.

Since the GIS SE is a place where I can find plenty of good examples on this particular topic (many of my answers involve the VL), I was wondering if I can/may/allowed to include questions+answers related to the Virtual Layer into my educational materials? Or I am breaking some legislative rules and the authors' copyrights.

For instance, in this reference ["Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow), it seems that the Creative Commons (CC) plays a key role, but I am not that much convinced and adamant after reading that thread. Moreover, I am not sure whether the same rules are applicable to a typical GIS bundle(description, text, pictures, code, and a sample of data) in comparison with a pure code shared over Stack Overflow.

Comment: Feel free to seek collaboration via the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis), and link from there back to here, but that part of your question is not about the GIS Stack Exchange so I've deleted it from your question.

Comment: I am not strong in rights laws, but I think that you can use the materials of the questions and answers, but only with a mandatory reference to the original sources...

Comment: You can always ask the users who posted the content you like. And credit them. That would also be a nice signal of recognition to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All content posted on GIS Stack Exchange is covered by the same licensing as on Stack Overflow and any other Stack Exchange site.

I think the place to start delving into what contraints may apply to your use is at [Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow have moved to CC BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0).